# FileSystemObject CopyFile: Unhanded Exception

Tags: vb.net, filesystemobject, file-copying

I'm having a problem with using `FileSystemObject.CopyFile`.  I think I'm using it correctly, from the forums I've read, but I am still getting the following compiler error:

> ArgumentException was unhandled: Value does not fall within expected range

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim testfolderchk
    testfolderchk = Dir("C:\Test\")
    Dim inforeader As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim filedestinationcheck = Dir("C:\Test2\")

  If testfolderchk <> "" Then 
        If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(testfolderchk, 4) = "test" Then
            inforeader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\Test" & testfolderchk)
            filetime = (inforeader.LastWriteTime)
            If testfolderchk = filedestinationcheck Then GoTo skipfile
            If testfolderchk = filedestinationcheck2 Then GoTo skipfile

        Else : GoTo skipfile
        End If
    End If

fso.CopyFile(testfolderchk, filedestinationcheck, True)
```

Comment: The `System.IO` namespace has all sorts of file related methods which are better suited to NET code than `FileSystemObject`.

Comment: Suggestions?  Anyone?

Comment: `Suggestions?`  Yes, dont use FSO and dont use `GoTo`.  And with just a little research you could find hundreds of file copy applets here

Comment: As @Plutonix has suggested. Look into the `System.IO` namespace. This has `Directory`, `DirectoryInfo`, `File`, `FileInfo` which should be all you need to get information and to copy files. Don't use `FileSystemObject`.

Comment: I'm unsure as well what you are doing here `("C:\Test" & testfolderchk)`. Wouldn't that effectively be `("C:\TestC:\Test\")`? Since `testfolderchk` has been assigned "C:\Test"

Comment: Suggesting I haven't researched the issue isn't helpful, because I have done that.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I was suggesting you could easily find .NET code written to show how to use the NET File IO methods and doesnt use `GoTo`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments you should scrap the use of `FileSystemObject` and use instead the `System.IO` namespace, specifically [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Provides properties and instance methods for the creation, copying, deletion, moving, and opening of files, and aids in the creation of FileStream objects. This class cannot be inherited.

With `FileInfo` you can use the method [CopyTo (String, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5axsfwbc(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Copies an existing file to a new file, allowing the overwriting of an existing file.

I have drafted up a bit of code to show you what I mean:

```
Dim folderToCheck As String = "C:\Test"
Dim destinationFolder As String = "C:\Test2"

Dim file As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(IO.Path.Combine(folderToCheck, "test.txt"))

Dim filetime As Date = file.LastWriteTime

file.CopyTo(IO.Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file.Name), True)
```

Note the use of [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Combines two strings into a path.

Comment: Thank you.  I did something similar and it ended up working nicely.  I appreciate it. @Bugs